# Bulk Insert with autoIncrement Primary Key Results in NULL Values for id Column in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

---

**Issue Summary:**
I'm experiencing an issue when performing a bulk insert using Sequelize with an `autoIncrement` primary key column. Even though I have configured the Sequelize model to auto-increment the `id` field and exclude it from insert operations, Sequelize is still trying to insert `NULL` values into the `id` column.

**Code Samples:**

Set up a Sequelize model with an `autoIncrement` primary key, similar to the following:

```js
const AnswerModel = sequalizeInstance.define(
    "Answer",
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        // ... other fields ...
    },
    {
        timestamps: false,
    }
);
```

Attempt to perform a bulk insert using `bulkCreate` on the model, excluding the `id` field from the data array:

```js
const dataToInsert = [
  { /* ... other fields ... */ },
  { /* ... other fields ... */ },
  // ...
];

AnswerModel.bulkCreate(dataToInsert)
  .then(() => {
    // Handle success...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error inserting data:', error);
  });
```

**Expected Behavior:**
The `id` column should be auto-incremented by the database, and Sequelize should not attempt to insert values into it during the bulk insert operation.

**Actual Behavior:**
Sequelize is trying to insert `NULL` values into the `id` column, resulting in a foreign key constraint violation.

Comment: Why would inserting a null value generate a foreign key violation? I cannot see a FK defined on the id field.

Comment: I don't know  this is the Sequelize Error
 {
  name: 'SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError',
  parent: Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mind_shift`.` answers`, CONSTRAINT `answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`QuestionID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 

I solve the problem, put it as a RESTRICT

Comment: you should have a separate question id field somewhere in your answer model that references a question